# NTLM authentication using Go

Tags: authentication, go, ntlm, exchangewebservices

I need to authenticate to Exchange EWS from both Windows and Unix.

Is there any library or anything I could use to do that in Go? I saw there is [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/), a NTLM proxy I could exec(). But I am not sure if this is working for Exchange.. Someone seemed to have problems [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/forums/forum/702676/topic/4575207).

Comment: You can always try calling [libntlm](http://www.nongnu.org/libntlm/) or something similar with [cgo](http://blog.golang.org/2011/03/c-go-cgo.html).

Comment: But then I couldn't use any normal package like `http` from Go, because NTLM only authenticates a connection.. And I can't reuse a already established and authenticated connection from the lib - or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If exchange supports kerberos you can try gokerb (https://github.com/jmckaskill/gokerb). NTLM is on my list ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ended up using Basic Auth for now, but am still searching for other methods to authenticate.